# Update column value by loop without where condition

Tags: mysql

I have following table with about 15.000 rows :

```
+--------------+-------------+
| member_index | member_id   |
+--------------+-------------+
|        59084 |             |
|       155647 | -8zkkozg    |
|       140550 | -sanofi-    |
|       153323 | ..pgdpta    |
```

I need to loop over each row to update member_index without `where` condition  or `where` with something like offset ,just want loop from first record to end to update it

Is this impossible ?

//Update expecte output :

```
+--------------+-------------+
| member_index | member_id   |
+--------------+-------------+
|   59084_abcd |             |
|   55647_efgh | -8zkkozg    |
|  140550_ijkl | -sanofi-    |
|  153323_gmop | ..pgdpta    |
```

The append part (`_efgh`...) is get from a procedure

```
declare append varchar(20)
CALL getAppendPart(append)

for loop ..//this part what I need to ask

   UPDATE table tbl set member_index = concat(member_index ,append)
```

Comment: can you gve us sample output?

Comment: thanks ,expect output updated

Comment: is this what you are looking at `update table_name set member_index = concat(member_index,'_suff')` ?

Comment: and from where `abcd,efgh,..` for member index are generated ?

Comment: The append part (_efgh...) is get from a procedure

Answer (score 0):

use MySQL `concat()` :-

```
update table set member_index=concat(member_index,'_',
substring('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
rand(@seed:=round(rand(@lid)*4294967296))*36+1, 4))
```

Comment: sorry , I have mistake in expected output , the update part is not the same for each row

Comment: I updated question for more clear , so sorry for that :(